# python library to compare a .wav with mic input?

Tags: python, audio, comparison, wav

I need a python library or module or whatever that can compare a .wav file to microphone input without too too much code. Sample code would be cool too. TY!

Comment: Any more info on what you mean by "compare" ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a library already for that, but if you have the microphone input as a WAV file as well, you can use the [`wave`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) and [`audioop`](http://docs.python.org/library/audioop.html) modules and write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to compare something like, what words people are saying, this would have to be a fairly complex piece of code. You could directly compare them at a frequency/wave level, but you'll very rarely if ever get a match.